Does anyone know of any sources on the evolution of the three p'sukim added onto the end of Aanim Zmiros (Shir Hakavod)?
Looking for how, when and why these 3 verses were added. I have no sources for this and find the question intriguing.
The additional three verses are [image is from Authorised Daily Prayer Book 2nd Edition Seventh Impression, page 84]


Welcome to MiYodeya David and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Hi David. Can you list the three verses you are asking about?

Thanks for your intriguing questions! I hope you get interesting answers, and I look forward to reading them. Could your please [edit] both question posts to flesh out the post bodies? The post body itself should present the question completely, independently of the title. And the more pertinent details, such as those sought by @DoubleAA, that you include, the more readily your questions will be appreciated by readers and answered.

By having had quite many siddurim in my hands, the first verse seems to be a somewhat earlier addition than the second
